# 1gb database with only two records

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I identified an issue with an infrastructure I created on the Google Cloud Platform and would like to ask the community for help.

A charge was made that I did not expect, as theoretically it would be almost impossible for me to pass the limits of the free tier. But I noticed that my database is huge, with 1gb and growing, and there are some very heavy buckets.

My database is managed by a Django APP, and accessing the tool's admin panel there are only 2 records in production. There were several backups and things like that, but it wasn't me.

Can anyone give me a guide on how to solve this?

Comment: What kind of database is it ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B it's MySQL

Comment: Did you created a simple VM and installed MySQL by yourself or used a Marketplace solution ? I'd like to reproduce your case if possible to check.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I don't really remember, it's been a while. I recreated it now and paid attention to go for the cloudsql option and choose not to expand the storage automatically, but I believe that again I created a database that will cause me the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you manage the database yourself, i.e. it is not [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql). Databases pre-allocate files in larger chunks in order to be efficient on writes. You can check this yourself - write additional 100k records, most likely size will not change.

Comment: I created a new instance, and this time from the cloudsql option and made sure to check for storage not to increase by itself. This is enough? How can I make sure it is a database managed by Google and not by me? Will there be costs for few registrations, like 10 for example?

Comment: Cloud SQL option means that it is managed by Google in terms of infrastructure. Please, refer to the pricing guide here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing

Comment: How can I be sure that a running instance is managed by cloudsql?

Comment: Go to [Cloud SQL](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances) and it will say how many sql instances you have. If you see the "create instance" window that means that you don't have any Google managed SQL instances and the onw we're talking about is a standalone one. You can also check [Deployment Manger](https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments) to see if you deployed one from the marketplace or it's a standalone VM with MySQL installed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Cloud SQL](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances) and it will say how many sql instances you have. If you see the "create instance" window that means that you don't have any Google managed SQL instances and the one we're talking about is a standalone one.

You can also check [Deployment Manger](https://console.cloud.google.com/deployments) to see if you deployed one from the marketplace or it's a standalone VM with MySQL installed manually.

I made a simple experiment and deployed (from Marketplace) a MySQL 5.6 on top of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Initial DB size was over 110MB - but there are some records in it initially (schema, permissions etc) so it's not "empty" at all.

It is still weird that your DB is 1GB already. Try to deploy new one (if your use case permits that). Maybe this is some old DB that was used for some purpose and all the content deleted afterwards but some "trash" still remains and takes a lot of space.

Or - [it may well be exactly as NeatNerd said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694095/12257250) - that DB will allocate some space due to performance issues and optimisation.

If I have more details I can give you better explanation.